# Why can't I sign a friend's GPG key, even though I can sign git commits and messages just fine?

Tags: gnupg, digital-signature

I'm trying to sign someone's GPG key, and keep getting a strange error:

```
# for example
$ gpg --sign-key cfeck@kde.org 

pub  rsa2048/DBD2CE893E2D1C87
     created: 2017-06-27  expires: never       usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
sub  rsa2048/C714D46F0AB88BAA
     created: 2017-06-27  expires: never       usage: E   
[ unknown] (1). Christoph Feck <cfeck@kde.org>

gpg: using "5F6E4C40D1D8450B" as default secret key for signing

pub  rsa2048/DBD2CE893E2D1C87
     created: 2017-06-27  expires: never       usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
 Primary key fingerprint: F232 75E4 BF10 AFC1 DF69  14A6 DBD2 CE89 3E2D 1C87

     Christoph Feck <cfeck@kde.org>

Are you sure that you want to sign this key with your
key "Caleb Xavier Berger (Master Hardware Key) <caleb.x.berger@gmail.com>" (5F6E4C40D1D8450B)

Really sign? (y/N) y
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key

Key not changed so no update needed.
```

But I can run commands like `gpg --sign` just fine, and get signed messages as you would expect from that:

```
$ gpg --sign --armor
gpg: using "5F6E4C40D1D8450B" as default secret key for signing
memes!
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

owGbwMvMwCG29qzhPD2zoGLG07xJDMlt091zU3NTixW5OkpZGMQ4GGTFFFlSpYV7
7ny+uvHfx612MOWsTEC1PgxcnAIwkUNmDP/UOBcekTt6v2qurMVGg5cf16Qsjytq
aXRKYGj8sT8vZ0IkI8N/u85nUy5s83SZ0cesEB/2LOfA3ZWNMx5ucKpd9okrazcz
AA==
=/7Ap
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

In case it's relevant, my secret key is stored on a YubiKey that I have plugged in throughout. It shows up fine with `gpg --list-secret-keys` and `gpg --card-edit` appears to be working correctly as well.

What's different about keysigning that might be breaking things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I didn't actually have a subkey available to sign *keys* (which is different from signing data and such).

```
$ gpg2 -K
/home/caleb/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------------
sec#  ed25519 2020-10-18 [SC]
      857536546D2A161825C8F1E35F6E4C40D1D8450B
uid           [ultimate] Caleb Xavier Berger (Master Hardware Key) <caleb.x.berger@gmail.com>
ssb>  cv25519 2020-10-18 [E]
ssb>  ed25519 2020-10-18 [A]
ssb>  ed25519 2020-10-18 [S]
```

Note that the only key here with the `C` capability is listed with `sec#` - `gpg` doesn't actually know how to get this secret key, so I can't certify keys from this system.

(Thankfully, I have a copy of that part of the key in a secure location!)