# How to sign somebody else's gpg key when master key somewhere else?

Tags: gnupg

Along the same lines as this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1755327/why-cant-i-sign-a-friends-gpg-key-even-though-i-can-sign-git-commits-and-mess), in which they never posted the solution.

How to finally do it?

What steps to follow to sign somebody else's key?

I am just starting to use GPG and run into the same issue.

My keys look as follows (same as the other post):

```
gpg -K
/home/<user-id>/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
--------------------------------
sec#  ed25519 2023-05-18 [C]
      <bla bla and hex-seq>
uid           [ultimate] First Last <first.last@mycompany.com>
ssb   cv25519 2023-05-18 [E]
ssb   ed25519 2023-05-18 [S]
ssb   ed25519 2023-05-18 [A]
```

And somewhere else in some secure spot, I have:

```
<hex-seq>.priv.asc
<hex-seq>.pub.asc
<hex-seq>.rev
<hex-seq>.sub_priv.asc
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Signing other people's keys is a "certification" and needs the `[C]` key (which is always the master key), indeed that's one of the reasons why some people recommend splitting it off.

1. Temporarily import the private half of your master subkey.
2. Sign someone else's key.
3. Remove the private half of your master subkey again.

Comment: Ah, I see; so, that's one time when one needs to bring in the stashed away master key. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and it's one of the reasons people split it off; certifications [C] are always done using the master key.